# Macro to stringify the result of an arithmetic expression

Tags: c++, clang, c-preprocessor, stringification

Is it possible to write a preprocessor macro which stringifies the *result* of an integer arithmetic expression in clang?

For example:

```
#define WIDTH 20
#define HEIGHT 30

int main()
{
    puts("The total area is " INT_TO_STRING(WIDTH*HEIGHT));
}
```

I know it's possible to do in Visual C++, using its `__if_exists` built-in macro. Here is the Visual C++ implementation:

```
#define STRINGIZE_(n) #n
#define STRINGIZE(n) STRINGIZE_(n)

template<bool> struct static_if_t;
template<> struct static_if_t<true> {};
#define static_if(c) __if_exists(static_if_t<(c)>)

template<int N> struct Abs { enum { n = N < 0 ? -N : N }; };

#define INT_TO_STRING(value) \
    static_if ((value)<0) {"-"} \
    UINT_TO_STRING(Abs<(value)>::n)

#define UINT_TO_STRING(value) \
    static_if ((value)>=1000000000) {INT_TO_STRING_HELPER((value),1000000000)} \
    static_if ((value)>=100000000)  {INT_TO_STRING_HELPER((value),100000000)} \
    static_if ((value)>=10000000)   {INT_TO_STRING_HELPER((value),10000000)} \
    static_if ((value)>=1000000)    {INT_TO_STRING_HELPER((value),1000000)} \
    static_if ((value)>=100000)     {INT_TO_STRING_HELPER((value),100000)} \
    static_if ((value)>=10000)      {INT_TO_STRING_HELPER((value),10000)} \
    static_if ((value)>=1000)       {INT_TO_STRING_HELPER((value),1000)} \
    static_if ((value)>=100)        {INT_TO_STRING_HELPER((value),100)} \
    static_if ((value)>=10)         {INT_TO_STRING_HELPER((value),10)} \
                                     INT_TO_STRING_HELPER((value),1)

#define INT_TO_STRING_HELPER(value,place) \
    static_if ((value)/place%10==0) {"0"} \
    static_if ((value)/place%10==1) {"1"} \
    static_if ((value)/place%10==2) {"2"} \
    static_if ((value)/place%10==3) {"3"} \
    static_if ((value)/place%10==4) {"4"} \
    static_if ((value)/place%10==5) {"5"} \
    static_if ((value)/place%10==6) {"6"} \
    static_if ((value)/place%10==7) {"7"} \
    static_if ((value)/place%10==8) {"8"} \
    static_if ((value)/place%10==9) {"9"}
```

Can it be done in clang?

Comment: Why???   Is is this a performance thing?

Comment: Does the preprocessor do the math for you in the first place?

Comment: In the VC++ implementation, the math is done by the compiler when it attempts to calculate the `bool` template parameter. The preprocessor can do some arithmetics too (`#if 2+2==4` works), but I don't see any way to use that to solve this particular problem.

Comment: That's not C code! And whatever this is meant to solve: use a maintanable approach. This is a debugging nightmare.

Comment: Oops, you're right, this is C++ of course. And I wouldn't say that code like this is complicated, or even unusual - see e.g. the way the Linux kernel does compile-time asserts.

Comment: Why not simply use string streams?    Or do you intend to use the strings produced at compile time?

Comment: Yes, the result must be a string literal, because of constraints that are outside the scope of this particular question.